# AngularJS Infinite $digest Loop error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-infdig

I'm trying to populate a list of divs using ng-repeat. I'm also using a framework that has depths (so i can navigate through the list's elements).

To set this depth I need to call `getTotalDepths` function that checks the current index of the list item with a `tempIndex` value. If they are different it should increase the total depths and then return the `totalDepths` value.

After I run it, the following error occurs (about 25000 times):

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/infdig?

HTML:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-list" focusable data-focusable-depth="{{getTotalDepths($index)}}">
        <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{item.picture}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.totalDepths = -1;
var tempIndex = -1;
var x;

$scope.getTotalDepths = function (index) {
    x = $scope.totalDepths;
    if (tempIndex != index) {
        tempIndex = index;
        x = $scope.totalDepths += 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Note: The error occurs when i increase `totalDepths` in this line:

```
x = $scope.totalDepths += 1;
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: AngularJS calls `getTotalDepths` several times for each `index` and always gets different resuts, because it is not pure function and has side effects - `$scope.totalDepths += 1`. You should refactor your code.

Comment: Oh I see, is there something you suggest I could do?

Comment: Can you show example of desired HTML result, i.e. values of `data-focusable-depth`?

Comment: This ng-repeat is inside an other ng-repeat. The goal is to have the same depth number in all list items of each list. ex:
List1: all `data-focusable-depth="0"`
List2: all `data-focusable-depth="1"` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Slava I solved the problem.

Calling the getTotalDepths() the way I did was a big mistake as Angular calls it in every cycle, and the function returns different result every time.

I fixed it by simply calling the function inside the ng-init like so:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="depth = getTotalDepths($index)">
    <div class="item-list" focusable data-focusable-depth="{{depth}}">
        <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{item.picture}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```